# mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the hang of using custom session handlers to store session data in a MySQL database. However, I keep getting the following warning:

```
mysql_close(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource
```

Here's the code I'm using, which I got from [here](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database):

```
function _open(){

    global $_sess_db;
    $_sess_db = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "******");
    if ($_sess_db) {
        return mysql_select_db('style', $_sess_db);
    }
    return false;
}

function _close(){
    global $_sess_db;
    return mysql_close($_sess_db); //error happens here
}
```

The full text of the error message ultimately points to the final "return mysql_close($_sess_db);" line. I can confirm that the mysql_connect info does in fact work, and I do have the rest of the session handler functions defined as well.

And in case it helps, I get these errors immediately upon page load, without actually calling any of the session handler functions, and without having any current sessions open.

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is your variable scope. the global keyword does nothing if the variable was not defined outside of a function first. an alternative would be to use the super global $GLOBALS['_sess_db'], or to first define $_sess_db outside of any functions.

Comment: on top of that, if you are not using multiple databases, you may not need to specify which DB connection you would like to close, as it automatically closes the last connection opened if no argument is passed.

Comment: also, non-persistent db connections automatically close at the end of your script, so closing the db connection may not even be needed depending on your project.

Comment: Yep, variable scope was the issue. I'm no longer getting that error. However, after starting the session, i'm trying to do $_SESSION['uid'] = 4. But I don't see this getting reflected in the database at all. Since I have defined a session_write function, that custom function should be getting used for $_SESSION['uid'] = ... right? In that case, would the problem be in my custom handler function?

Comment: i mean i don't even understand. why are you putting session variables into a database? session variables are automatically saved for the next page that that user requests, and will remain saved for the duration of the session. if you want something to go into a database, you just put it in the database and don't get sessions involved. what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: My understanding is that saving session session variables in a database is the most secure way to do it; otherwise you have to save the variables in a file on the user's computer, whether in a cookie or other type of file. And that in turn makes the data more vulnerable. Obviously I need (and plan) to read up more on PHP security, but I thought this was the best way to go about it. If you have any reading recommendations, I'd much appreciate them :)

Comment: @maxedison session variables do not get stored on the users system. they are stored solely on your server.

Comment: Yeah I'd just use normal session variables (not in database) for these sort of things...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some debug printouts in _open() and _close() and see if they are called when you're not expecting them to be.

Comment: I guess that I'm not sure when they're supposed to be called. Should they not be called automatically every time a page loads? That's what's happening. In other words, I'm not calling session_start(), and no prior session exists.

Comment: Also, I don't have sessions set to autostart in the php.ini file.